# Fresh Lubuntu 20.04: WiFi "deauthenticating" immediately

Tags: networking, lubuntu, network-manager, iwlwifi

I have a fresh installation of Lubuntu 20.04. WiFi worked on Lubuntu 16.04, it works on Windows on the same laptop (dual boot), and on two Android devices. But for some reason Lubuntu cannot connect to my WiFi AP anymore. With patience, reboots and several trials it sometimes does work. I tested my mobile hotspot, and it worked fine out of the box. So what's wrong with my wired AP?
I am not 100% sure if it's related to the fresh installation. I tried other distros, and they showed the same issue, and it may have worked for some short time right after the installation.

Based on Google searches, have tried the following: renamed the interface to wlan0, added a different DNS server, set the country (though `iw reg get` continues to shows `00`), changed the WiFi channel, disabled 5GHz, toggled the WiFi switches on the laptop, changed the power saving option from 3 to 2.

dmesg always shows:

```
[  828.327674] wlp10s0: authenticate with 18:9c:27:xx:yy:zz
[  828.329482] wlp10s0: send auth to 18:9c:27:xx:yy:zz (try 1/3)
[  828.335471] wlp10s0: authenticated
[  828.337021] wlp10s0: associate with 18:9c:27:xx:yy:zz (try 1/3)
[  828.354096] wlp10s0: RX AssocResp from 18:9c:27:xx:yy:zz (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=3)
[  828.373117] wlp10s0: associated
[  840.379576] wlp10s0: deauthenticating from 18:9c:27:xx:yy:zz by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
```

I am using NetworkManager. I have uploaded the wireless-info.txt to https://drive.google.com/file/d/1L_eYEg9dhDBhojFDitkX_4kENhqosebi/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

So it turns our my cable router (provided by Vodafone Germany) received an upgrade two days ago. That's when the issues started. A factory reset resolved everything. Though I don't understand how the same wireless adapter (when booting Win10) *could* connect even before the reset...